# Как выбрать даты, касающиеся заданных периодов?

Tags: mysql

Нужно составить запрос для выборки дат из таблицы, которые так или иначе касаются заданных дат. Т.е. существует таблица `price_season`. В таблице содержаться столбцы с датами `begin_date` и `end_date`. Из этой таблицы нужно выбрать те поля, которые так или иначе касаются задданных.

Например:
имеются две заданные даты от и до : `2012-04-01 - 2012-04-30` , а в таблице содержится несколько дат:
1)`2012-03-27 - 2012-03-29`
2)`2012-04-04 - 2012-05-07`
3)`2012-03-29 - 2012-05-01`
Нужно, чтобы были выбраны даты 1) и 2), т.к. они касаются заданного периода. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить нужный запрос!

Answer (score 2):

как то так:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  price_season
WHERE
  begin_date in (select
                   begin_date
                 from
                   price_season
                 where
                   begin_date<'2012-03-29' and begin_date>'2012-04-04')
  and begin_date>'2012-03-27' and begin_date<'2012-05-07'
```

PS: А для чего у вас второе поле с временем ? оно должно участвовать в запросе ?

Answer (score 2):

То есть задаётся диапазон дат и нужно проверить, какие из имеющихся диапазонов в него попали? Тут нужно попробовать три варианта:

1. дата начала попадает в заданный диапазон, тогда диапазон подходит;
2. дата начала не попадает, а дата окончания попадает, тогда тоже подходит;
3. никто не попадает в заданный диапазон, но дата начала меньше диапазона, а дата окончания — больше, тогда тоже подходит.

Остальные случаи не подходят. Такую проверку делать для каждого диапазона.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  price_season
WHERE
  begin_date BETWEEN 2012-04-01 AND 2012-04-30
  OR end_date BETWEEN 2012-04-01 AND 2012-04-30;
```

Comment: Нет. Если промежуток в таблице покрывает весь искомый, то этот код не сработает.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Вам большое за отзывчивость! У меня получился такой вариант:

```
SELECT id,id_hotel_number,begin_season,end_season 
FROM price_season 
WHERE (begin_season <= '2012-04-01' AND end_season >= '2012-04-01'
      AND id_hotel_number = '105') OR (end_season >= '2012-04-30'
      AND begin_season <= '2012-04-30' AND id_hotel_number = '105')
      OR (begin_season >= '2012-04-01' AND end_season <= '2012-04-30' 
      AND id_hotel_number = '105')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте опцию редактирования Вашего вопроса, чтобы указать дополнительную информацию. Кнопку "Опубликовать ответ" следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.

Comment: @Etki Вроде, это и есть "исчерпывающий ответ". Другой вопрос, есть ли в нём польза...

Comment: @Athari лол, понятия не имел, что он автоматом комментарии ставит. Это вроде как в идеале должно быть правкой вопроса.

Comment: @Etki В "низкокачественной" очереди, если выбрать любой пункт кроме первого ("комментарии не нужны"), то, собственно, добавится комментарий. Для старых постов пользы от комментариев немного, а комментарии к новым пользователи увидят и намотают на ус. / Если после нескольких предложенных решений автор нашёл своё, то он может запостить решение как отдельный ответ, это нормально, по-моему (если ответ не повторяет ответов других юзеров, конечно).

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял условие, то данную задачу должен решать следующий запрос:

```
SELECT  id,  id_hotel_number,  begin_season,  end_seasonFROM  price_seasonWHERE      id_hotel_number  = '105'  AND begin_season    <= '2012-04-30'  AND end_season      >= '2012-04-01'
```

Случай когда ценовой сезон полностью перекрывает рассматриваемый промежуток времени тоже учитывается.

---

Общий принцип решения:  Дата начала ценового сезона(**begin__season**) должна быть меньше конца рассматриваемого периода(**до**)  И дата конца ценового сезона(**end__season**) должна быть больше начала рассматриваемого периода(**от**).

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы так:

```
select * from price_season where begin_date <= @max_limit and end_date >= @min_limit
```